# data rendering issue after button is clicked in react

Tags: reactjs

I am having a data rendering issue in react. Somehow, data is not automatically updated after it's updated in the server side.  I can't put all the code in here, cuz the code is kind of lengthy. so i pasted/renamed some variables. Even if some variables are missing, please understand.  Basically, I have a button on the page and when the button is clicked, the status changes to 'UPLOADING' and the function `checkIfDataExists` is called to fetch data from the server side and data should be automatically updated without page refresh, but when I test this, data is successfully retrieved from the server side, but the updated data is not rendered. I see 'successful...' on the Console. Is there anything wrong?

```
const Settings: React.FC<IProps> = props => {
  const { orgId } = props
  const password = 'dummy'
  const { data } = httpCall(`/${orgId}/${userId}/settings`)

  return (
    <div>
      {data && <SettingsForm data={data} password={password} {...props} />}
    </div>
  )
}

const SettingsForm: React.FC<Settings & IProps> = ({
  data,
  password
}) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<'ERROR' | 'DONE' | 'UPLOADING'>()
  const service = getServiceInstance(data.organizationId)

  function checkIfDataExists(user: any) {
    return () => {
      httpCall
        .getClient(user.id)
        .then(value => {
          console.log('successful...')
          data.modeUsername = value.modeUsername
          data.modePassword = value.modePassword
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setStatus('ERROR')
        })
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!status) return
   switch (status) {
     case 'UPLOADING': {
       const timer = setInterval(
         checkIfDataExists({ id: data.id }),
         2000
       )
       return () => clearInterval(timer)
     }
   }
 }, [status, client
])

<div className="info-section">
    <p className="detail">Username</p>
    <p>{data.modeUsername}</p>
</div>
<div className="info-section">
    <p className="detail">Password</p>
    <p>{data.modePassword}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you log out the actual data? You may not catch error with .then when you use fetch api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that after you `setInterval` an API you didn't set in the state to trigger the component to rerender. You don't need to be explicit to define `resData` to `data` because if you define data already `useState` already it types.

```
const SettingsForm: React.FC<Settings & IProps> = ({
  data,
  password
}) => {
  const [resdata,setResData] = useState(data)
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<'ERROR' | 'DONE' | 'UPLOADING'>()
  const service = getServiceInstance(data.organizationId)

  function checkIfDataExists(user: any) {
    return () => {
      httpCall
        .getClient(user.id)
        .then(value => {
          console.log('successful...')
          setResData({
             modeUsername: value.modeUsername,
             modePassword: value.modePassword,
          })
          // data.modeUsername = value.modeUsername
          // data.modePassword = value.modePassword
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setStatus('ERROR')
        })
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!status) return
   switch (status) {
     case 'UPLOADING': {
       const timer = setInterval(
         checkIfDataExists({ id: data.id }),
         2000
       )
       return () => clearInterval(timer)
     }
   }
 }, [status, client
])

<div className="info-section">
    <p className="detail">Username</p>
    <p>{resdata.modeUsername}</p>
</div>
<div className="info-section">
    <p className="detail">Password</p>
    <p>{resdata.modePassword}</p>
</div>
```